# Why is Computer Architecture in $2^n$ bits?

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits

I have always wondered why is computer architecture in $2^n$ bits. We have **8 / 16 / 32 / 64-bit** microprocessors or for that matter other parts of computer are also in power of 2 bits.

The only logic I could understand from my reasoning is that usually computer design process starts from *lower* amount of bits. **For example :** Say I want to design a *Full adder* to add `16 bit` numbers. So I would first design a digital circuit to add `2 bits` (one from number A and other form number B). Then I would replicate this circuit `16 times`. So this will give me `16-bit` full adder.

Is my reasoning correct ? Is there some other reason also ?

Comment: Note that early computers didn't necessarily follow this convention. For example, [EDSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_Delay_Storage_Automatic_Calculator) had 1024 memory locations, each holding 17 or 18 bits. [UNIVACs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC) had all kinds of word sizes (at least 18, 30, 36 bits).

Comment: Did you ever notice that balanced binary trees have a number of nodes at each level that is a power of 2. Strange coincidence!

Comment: @DavidRicherby I Agree. But $2^n$ has become a general standard and I am curious to know why..

Comment: @babou Is that intended as an oblique hint? If so, it's so oblique that I don't understand it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby It is more a search suggestion than a hint. I am not very happy with
the answers. I was only noting that binary structure are used a lot,
including in places where we could conceivably use non-binary
structures (ternary or others). Trying to identify the reasons for the
binary bias in other situation might give clues for this specific
aspect of convergence of memory unit size on povers of two. One clear
aspect is that bits are used optimally when addressing spaces that are
a power of two.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I fail to see your distinction regarding my comment. I did not say
`memory size`, but `memory unit size`, meaning the size of words, or
that of the bus. When adressing withing a word, you probably want optimal use of the bits, since any "fragmentation" on the use of addressing bits will give a high percentage of loss, on such a small address space.

Comment: @babou Oh, sorry. I'm not familiar with the term "memory unit size" and took it to mean "the size of the memory unit", i.e., the total amount of memory available. I'd say "word size" for the thing you mean.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You are right. I realized too late that it could be read ambiguously. I did not use `word` because I was trying not to be too specific, as there might be several small units in use for the same architecture.

Comment: Look up "barrel shifter".

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, for instance, look at the memory bus width in modern day GPUs, they would have values of 192, 384, 768(while 128, 256.... are common).

One could argue that 192 is a sum of powers of 2 (2^7+2^6), sure, but what number isn't?

That being said, any memory modules directly associated with a microprocessor or a microcontroller will have capacities in powers of 2. Traditionally registers will be 8,16, 32 or 64 bits long (though 10-bit and other non conventional widths exist).

A processor (or controller) with an n-bit register can address upto 2^n addresses (i.e, 0-(2^n)-1 bytes). Hence without changing the processor, one can extend the memory associated with it although exceeding the addressing space beyond what the processor can manage will be redundant.

In many DSPs, the memory associated with the processor is in 2^n multiples as many of the signal processing algorithms can be made very efficient when calculating this way.

Comment: Perhaps the point of 192 is not that it's a sum of powers of two, or even a sum of two powers of two, but that it's the sum of two consecutive powers of two, i.e., half-way between two powers of two.  (Not sure why that would be relevant to anything, though). The rest of your answer doesn't really address the question, though. Sure, with an $n$-bit register, you can address $2^n$ memory locations. But why is $n$ itself typically a power of two?

Comment: Note that, in some cases (not GPUs) the memory bus width is not a power of two because of EDC bits (error detection & correction. Sometimes just detection.).

Comment: @DavidRicherby The Intel 4004 was a 4 bit processor, no reason for this number, it was what was possible at the time... Then later came 8-bit(8008..), 16-bit and so on. This had become the industry standard. So every other manufacturer was just following standards. Back in the day, Moore's law was applicable practically up until 7 or 8 years ago when some physical limitations of silicon had started to show. So, the number of logic modules they could fit doubled and that might explain the 2^n pattern. This trend stopped at 64 bit as it can already address an impractical amount of memory.

Comment: @DavidRicherby That 64-bit limit is for general purpose processors alone. Higher register widths are used SIMD or MIMD operations as in DSPs or stand alone media processors (which technically are DSPs)

Comment: @d34df3tu5 .."_This had become the industry standard_" My Question is this only, Why has this become an industry standard, what convenience does it give the "industry". Is _"easy of replication"_ (as I mentioned in question) the only  reason ?

Comment: @d34df3tu5 Also my Question is not about "_what other architecures exists other than_ $2^n$ _bits_" but it is about _why $2^n$ is so popular_.

Comment: Computers using 3 levels logic have existed, but it is simpler to use binary bits. Counting binary numbers, addresses, naturally generates power-of-two busses, register widths...

Comment: @SimpleGuy I mentioned it before, I mention it again... What started as a possibility and then doubling of the same number due to Moore's law -- advancement in technology, it has become an industry standard. Also, certain algorithms are efficient and faster when done on powers of 2. Any divide and conquer algorithm, for example, can be divided up to it's individual parts (then conquered?). Since computers back then were not parallel, dividing to single bits made computation efficient.

Comment: @TEMLIB Counting in binary does *not* "naturally generate power-of-two busses, register widths, ..." For example, it's perfectly natural to count in binary on your ten fingers. It's natural that your memory would contain $2^k$ words for some $k$ but the actual question is why the registers and addresses themselves tend to contain $2^\ell$ bits for some $\ell$, leading to address spaces of size $2^{2^\ell}$, rather than arbitrary powers of two.

Comment: @d34df3tu5 I don't buy the divide and conquer explanation. The most efficient way to do divide and conquer is often to stop dividing when the input gets small. For example, you might compute on a 12-bit quantity by dividing into two sixes, then four threes and then solving those three-bit quantities iteratively. I don't buy Moore's law, either. It's only approximate and what says that you have to wait until the transistor count doubles? Why did nobody say "Hey, we have these 16-bit computers but now we can fit 50% more transistors on the chip so let's build a 24-bit computer!"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby: Yes it does. Some DSPs have 24bits or 48bits data/instruction busses but they are not suited for byte level access. Calculating byte locations within a 24bits bus requires an addition. For power of two busses and registers, it is just multiplexing the right lane.

Answer (score -1):

Some say that the IBM STRETCH (1961) introduced 8bits bytes :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_7030_Stretch

Until the late 70s, computers used other sizes and multiples, for example 36bits = 8 characters of 6 bits.
Early computers used only uppercase letters and numbers, using 6bits per character was more efficient.

Anyway, ask wikipedia : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-bit, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/18-bit...

There can be several explanations for the fact that all modern computers use 8bits bytes and multiples thereof. All monolithic microprocessors used that (8080, 6502...), 7 or 8bits ASCII was necessary for making text in uppercase and lowercase with internationalisation. Using powers of two all the way down must be appealing for computer designers...

Comment: ".. _There can be several explanations for the fact that all modern computers use 8bits bytes and multiples thereof_" What are those ? The question is about that only.

Comment: I though I gave some hints as why 8bits may be appealing. Explanations can be found by reading about old computers, but there is no simple answer. And adders can have any width, there is no benefit to have a power of two. IEEE double precision FPUs use 53 bits adders.